# MVC 5 - Best practice for handling dates inside and outside the USA

Tags: mvc, jquery, internationalization

I have an MVC 5 application that will be used world wide. A number of the pages in the app will require users to enter dates. I'll be using the jQuery datetimepicker plug-in to allow the user to select dates. Or they can enter them manually.

I'm curious what the best practice is for cultures where dates are entered in the dd/mm/yyyy format instead of mm/dd/yyyy? I could require all dates to be entered in mm/dd/yyyy format, which is the format my app is expecting, but I also don't want to cause too much angst with my users in other parts of the world.

Comment: just show the dd/MM/yyyy string as they are entering it, or use separate textboxes each with the proper label. either way this is a question for UX.SE

Comment: and I found the question related [to that for you.](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/most-user-friendly-form-fields-for-entering-date-time)

Comment: Very relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country – so figure out the user's locale and switch to the appropriate format (with a clear visual indication of the format you're expecting). Or just follow the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) – it's the international standard for good reasons. Or sidestep the issue via a graphical date picker that does not require textual input.

Comment: @amon: don't go by country based on IP. When I am traveling my location will be different from my regional preferences.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: Good find. Randy: don't go coding supporting different regional formats yourself. It's a waste of time and you'll probably miss stuff. Can't recall the name right now, but there is a jQuery internationalization / validation library that will/should take care of this. Search for those terms and you will find it.